# android listview and background color

Tags: android

hi am using following xml as my customlistview background

when am click an item it will highlight but it will not persist , it create only a clickable effect ,i want to be highlight a particular item in listview when click

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--ON FOCUS -->

<item
 android:state_focused="true"
 android:state_pressed="false"
 android:drawable="@@drawable/appcategoryselectedimg" />

<!--ON CLICK-->

<item
 android:state_focused="true"
 android:state_pressed="true"
 android:drawable="@@drawable/appcategoryselectedimg" />

<!--long touch and simple touch and release-->
<item
 android:state_focused="false"
 android:state_pressed="true"
 android:drawable="@@drawable/appcategoryselectedimg" />

<!--Default -->
<item  
 android:drawable="@color/transperent" /> 
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do a simple click. What you need is to define drawable for state_selected and `setSelected(true)` when the user clicks on an item.

Answer (score 3):

please refer the following code for the sample activity ListViewGeneralSampleProjectActivity.java

```
public class ListViewGeneralSampleProjectActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView sampleListView;
    private static int save = -1;
    int pos = 0;
    MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2","hai","Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2","hai","OS/2","hai", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2","hai","OS/2","hai" };
        sampleListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, values);

        sampleListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        sampleListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),position+" Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                adapter.setCurrent(position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

    }

}


MySimpleArrayAdapter.java

public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;
    private int selected=0;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        textView.setText(values[position]);
        if(position==selected)
        {
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }

        return rowView;
    }

    public void setCurrent(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.selected=position;
    }
}

main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

rowlayout.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```